# Facebook like box showing only partially

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm not very knowledgeable on the subject, so I beg your pardon if this is very basic.

I have a website at lolhehehe.com and whenever a user clicks on the Facebook like button at the bottom of every post the Facebook box won't show completely.

Is this an CSS issue? How can I solve it?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: When asking question on SO you should not just link to a page but show the relevant code with your question. Otherwise this question will not help anyone in future. Beside that your problem is most likely that the _like button_ is loaded using an `iframe`, which has a fixed dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your stylesheet:

```
body .fb_iframe_widget iframe {
max-width: none;
z-index: 2;
}
```

The button is an iframe and your theme was preventing the frame from growing. I added the z-index because other elements were overlapping without it.

Due to the positioning of your button, it may flow off the screen sometimes anyway. You may want to consider adjusting its position as well.